# How does MATLAB compute the real Schur decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, schur-decomposition

Let matrix `A` be defined as

```
A = [ 1     1     1     3
      1     2     1     1
      1     1     3     1
     -2     1     1     4 ];
```

The eigenvalues of `A` result from `eig(A)` as

```
   4.8121 + 0.0000i
   1.9202 + 1.4742i
   1.9202 - 1.4742i
   1.3474 + 0.0000i
```

Contrary to `eig(A)`, real Schur decomposition `[V,T]=schur(A)` results

```
T =

    4.8121    1.1972   -2.2273   -1.0067
         0    1.9202   -3.0485   -1.8381
         0    0.7129    1.9202    0.2566
         0         0         0    1.3474
```

whereas [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/schur.html) states that "*`T` has the real eigenvalues on the diagonal and the complex eigenvalues in 2-by-2 blocks on the diagonal*" which does not hold for the complex eigenvalues apparently. Is this an incorrect result? If not, then how it could be transformed to the form described in the documentation?

Comment: I think the complex eigenvalues are the same as those of the 2x2 block at the centre of the matrix T

Answer (score 1):

The central block of `T` defines a matrix that gives the complex eigenvalues of `A`

```
eig(T(2:3,2:3))
ans =

1.9202 + 1.4742i
1.9202 - 1.4742i
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. However,
1) the result does not match the documentation (according to my understanding at least) and,
2) I would like obtain the real Schur decomposition in the form described in the documentation (actually, I am not interested in the eigenvalues but working on a particular algorithm which relies on Schur decomposition).